# How can you make mechanics invariant under inversion of length?

Tags: symmetry, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, invariants

I read that in some string theories they are invariant under a change of distance from $r$ to $1/r$. I wondered what is the simplest theory or lagrangian in 4 dimensions that could have this property.

e.g. perhaps if we defined the gravitational potential between particles as $\frac{mG}{r+1/r}$.

But then this is not the solution to the typical Newtonion wave equation or a scalar potential nor a solution to GR. So these equations would have to be modified in some way. Is there a way to modify them to have this symmetry?

I think this would be correspond to the Universe having a minimum length scale.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick comments, perhaps to be expanded on:

You are thinking of T-duality. As Polchinski puts it in [his memoir](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09093) (section 7.2),

> A striking phenomenon special to strings was T-duality. If you put a
> particle in a box and make the box smaller and smaller, all that
> happens is that the excited states get heavier and heavier due to the
> momentum quantization. But for strings, after the box gets small
> enough, lighter and lighter states appear in the spectrum, and there
> is a perfect symmetry between a very large and very small box.
> Apparently there was a minimum length, something one might expect in
> the ultimate short distance theory. It was also an example of duality,
> the equivalence between the quantum theories of the large box and the
> small, but one that was visible even at weak coupling. And in more
> current parlance, it was an example of emergent space.

An interesting early paper if you can find it, is ["Duality in Statistical Mechanics and String Theory"](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.58.1597) by B. Sathiapalan, which relates it to [an order/disorder duality of the Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Wannier_duality).

Page 4 of this [2004 lecture](https://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ejmr/Tdualitylect.pdf) purports to give the simplest example: a free particle on a torus has the same partition function as a free particle on a dual torus.